# How to seperate multiple object in Array modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I want help about seperating those multiple pins made in array so they can be edited on their own.

I watched one tutorial and it says to go in edit mode, then press P to get to separation menu, and then separate by loose parts and that is all.

But as you can see on second picture, I have problem because when I do it deselect other pins, and show geometry of primary pin.
[image]

[image]

Comment: apply the modifier first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that after applying the modifier.

but the best solution so far is to just copy the object along an axis then repeat with shift + R

Comment: Thank you for fast answer, it worked!